# OAuth2 multiple servers accessing service

Tags: api, rest, authentication, oauth, restful-authentication

I have a server-side app that does some work with an API secured with OAuth 2.0. When I launch the app, I go through the OAuth authentication flow and get the access and refresh tokens.

Now, the problem is: my app works across multiple servers doing its thing.

Can I share the access token across all three servers or do I have to go and get a new one for each (which requires user interaction -- what a hassle!) ??  I noticed that Google's APIs call the access tokens "Bearer" tokens, which I'm assuming means they can be used by whomever has them in hand, but:

1. Is that common with other OAuth 2.0 APIs?  Are there better recommended practices?
2. Is that really the intended meaning?

Suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer.html) site,

> Any party in possession of a bearer token (a "bearer") can use it to
>   get access to the associated resources

This means that yes, you can share it across all three servers. The document I referenced isn't particular to an API, so it shouldn't matter whether it is Google or some other site.